# How to connect from MQTT javascript client to Mosquitto Server

Tags: javascript, mqtt, mosquitto

I tried connecting eclipse paho javascript client to my locally hosted mqtt mostquitto server but I am getting the following error:

```
1515729801: New connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 1883.
1515729801: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
```

Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>kajshdkjas</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paho-mqtt/1.0.1/mqttws31.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            var mqtt;
            var reconnectTimeout = 2000;
            var host = "127.0.0.1";
            var port = 1883;

            function onConnect() {
                console.log("Connected");
                message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("Hello World");
                message.destinationName = "sensor1";
                mqtt.send(message);
            }

            function MQTTconnect() {
                console.log("Connected to " + host + " " + port);
                mqtt = new Paho.MQTT.Client(host, port, "Clientjs");
                var options = {
                    timeout: 3,
                    onSuccess: onConnect,
                };
                mqtt.connect(options);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">MQTTconnect();</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried hosting it in both normally and inside my apache server. Where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to connect to a native MQTT port with the Javascript client from a webpage. This WILL NOT WORK, you can only connect to websocket endpoints from within a webpage.

You need to make sure that Mosquitto is configured to listen for websocket connections (most likely on a different port to 1883) and then put the correct port number into your page.